# TypeError: device.devices.map is not a function

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

I put products on the page and then I got an error, I can't figure out who this is connected with.

```
           const {device} = useContext(Context)

  91 | </div>
> 92 | <div className="inner-display-collection">
     | ^  93 |     {device.devices.map(device =>
  94 |         <CartGoods device={device}/>
  95 |     )}
```

the product itself:

```
   const CartGoodr = ({device}) => {
   const history = useHistory()
   return(
    <div className="inner-display-collection">
        <a key={device.id} href="" className="active-cart" onClick={() => history.push(DEVICE_ROUTE + '/' + device._id)} style={{textDecoration: 'none'}}>
            <div className="cart-good">
                <div className="wrapper-cart">
                    <img className="foto-cart" src="" alt="" />
                    <div className="display-info-cart">
                        <h3 className="text-price-cart" >{`${device.prise}₽`}</h3>
                    </div>
                    <div className="display-info-cart">
                        <h4 className="text-decription-cart">{device.descriptionMine}</h4> 
                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
   )
 }

  export default CartGoodr
```

that is, everything should work out, but this error crashes

Comment: Can you show us how or where you get the devices data? The error 'map is not a function' means that you're a invoking a map function on a non-array. E.g. object

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your **device.devices** object is empty. It must be an array to have access to that **.map** function, because it is only accessible on the arrays.

If you try to console log **device.devices** right before mapping elements, then you will see that it outputs rather *undefined, null, number* or *string* instead of *array*

```
const {device} = useContext(Context)
console.log(device.devices) // here
```

If that data is fetching through api request then you could add **loading** property to the device, set it to **true** before making the API request and when the data is fetched set it to **false**, then use it like so:

```
if(device.loading){
  return <p>Loading the device...</p>
}

// and here map through the device.devices or any other content of your component
```

Comment: _"The problem is that your device.devices object is empty."_ - It's not "empty". If `device.devices` would be `null` or `undefined` (in other words "empty") the error message would be a different one: `TypeError: device.devices is null/undefined` or `TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of null/undefined`. The error of OP tells us that `device.devices` has some value but it's not an array.